# Vagrant won't use static IP and Authentication failure on custom Centos Box

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, centos6, vagrantfile

I created a new base box off of `chef/centos-6.6`. While creating the box, everything worked as expected. The IP was correct and I was able tp use `vagrant ssh` without any issues. I then packed my box using `vagrant package --base vm_name --ouput devCentos-6.6.box` and uploaded it to my NAS.

I added the box using: `vagrant box add devCentos-6.6 http://10.1.1.120/boxes/devCentos-6.6.box`

Then ran: `vagrant init devCentos-6.6` and it generated the proper vagrantFile.

When I run: `vagrant up` I get this output:

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: bridged
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

The host is `Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS` and the guest is `Centos6.6`

Using: `VirtualBox 4.3.26 r98988` and `Vagrant 1.7.2`

I have `vb.gui = true` since I heard this seems to fix the issue but that's not the case here. When I use `vagrant ssh` I get a password prompt instead of letting me in.

When I am in the VM, I ran `ifconfig` and noticed the IP and the netmask are incorrect. The IP is: `10.0.2.15` and the netmask is: `255.255.255.0`

`service sshd status` shows: `openssh-daemon (pid  1082) is running...`

`ss -tlnp` shows:

```
State      Recv-Q Send-Q        Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port 
LISTEN     0      128                      :::22                      :::*      users:(("sshd",1082,4))
LISTEN     0      128                       *:22                       *:*      users:(("sshd",1082,3))
LISTEN     0      100                     ::1:25                      :::*      users:(("master",1314,13))
LISTEN     0      100               127.0.0.1:25                       *:*      users:(("master",1314,12))
LISTEN     0      128                       *:46201                    *:*      users:(("rpc.statd",945,8))
LISTEN     0      128                      :::443                     :::*      users:(("httpd",1327,6),("httpd",1334,6),("httpd",1335,6),("httpd",1336,6),("httpd",1337,6),("httpd",1338,6),("httpd",1339,6),("httpd",1340,6),("httpd",1341,6))
LISTEN     0      128                      :::43427                   :::*      users:(("rpc.statd",945,10))
LISTEN     0      50                        *:3306                     *:*      users:(("mysqld",1219,10))
LISTEN     0      128                      :::111                     :::*      users:(("rpcbind",925,11))
LISTEN     0      128                       *:111                      *:*      users:(("rpcbind",925,8))
LISTEN     0      128                      :::80                      :::*      users:(("httpd",1327,4),("httpd",1334,4),("httpd",1335,4),("httpd",1336,4),("httpd",1337,4),("httpd",1338,4),("httpd",1339,4),("httpd",1340,4),("httpd",1341,4))
```

`ip addr show` shows:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:6b:1c:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe6b:1cdd/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:d5:43:2a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I also tried this fix that I found but no luck:

```
sed -i 's|NM_CONTROLLED=yes|NM_CONTROLLED=no|g' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
service network restart
```

Also, when I was able to get past the key and network issue, I then had a mounting issue:

```
jpsimkins@jpUbuntu:~/Vagrant/centos-6.6$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'olympusatDev-Centos-6.6'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: centos-66_default_1429641033222_17210
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: bridged
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: 
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default: 
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if its present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /home/jpsimkins/Vagrant/centos-6.6
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3` vagrant /vagrant
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant` vagrant /vagrant

The error output from the last command was:

/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device
```

The guest tools are installed. They came from the original box (chef)

I am new to vagrant so I did as much as I could to isolate this issue. With everything I found so far on the web I haven't found a solution yet. Hopefully someone here can help me isolate this.

Let me know if you need any more details.

Thanks

My Vagrant config:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  #config.vm.box = "chef/centos-6.6"

  # Custom Box
  config.vm.box = "devCentos-6.6"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://10.1.1.120/boxes/devCentos-6.6.box"
  config.vm.hostname = "jpCentos"


  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "10.1.1.69", :netmask => "255.255.254.0", bridge: 'eth0'

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  config.vm.synced_folder "/home/jpsimkins/Sites", "/var/www/vhosts"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
    vb.gui = true

    # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:vagrant 
    vb.memory = "1024"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is what I did to solve all my issues:

**Fix the Key**

```
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant.pub -O ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**Removed the network rules**

```
sudo rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

**Fixed Guest Additions**

```
mkdir /media/cdrom
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
cd /media/cdrom
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

- Note: you will need to mount the Guest Additions CD from VirtualBox

**New Bug:** I now have an issue with Apache not starting due to when Vagrant mounts the shared folder (Apache fails initially as the mount is not mounted yet.) This seems to be a common issue but I couldn't find much on how to fix this.

**Fix httpd From Not Starting on Reload**

My solution to starting httpd after the shared folder is mounted was to work off the vagrant event: `vagrant-mounted`. I created a config file in `/etc/init` to handle this.

Run:
`sudo vi /etc/init/vagrant-mounted.conf`

Add this to the file:

```
# Start httpd when the vagrant-mounted event is fired
start on vagrant-mounted
exec service httpd start
```

Now that everything was fixed, I created a new box

```
vagrant package --base VM_BOX_NAME --output olympusatDevEnv-Centos-6.6.box
```

This solved my issue. Hopefully others will find this useful.